# MVC Custom role provider redirect to login page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I'm using a custom role provider and all seems to be working fine, if the user has permissions they are allowed in if not they are redirected to the login page.

But what I wanted to know is when they get redirected to the login page is there a way in the login page to set a message saying access denied or something. 
So for example I want something like below, User.FailedCustomRole? I'm not sure if something like this exists in an object somewhere:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if (User.FailedCustomRole) {
            ViewBag.Message = "No access to this page";
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- One way is to alter web.config to redirect user to the Logon page with a parameter of 1.

Alter your Logon Action to take a nullable int and if set, add a modelstate error

```
   public ActionResult LogOn(int? id)
    {
        //int id = Request.QueryString[;
        if (id != null)
        {
            LogOnModel model = new LogOnModel();
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please Login to use this page");

            return View(model);
        }
```

- A second way is to create an action filter that checks for login and redirects setting a Viewbag.LoginError

  ```
  public class CheckLoginFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
      public override void onactionexecuting(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
      {
                  if (Membership.GetUser() != null)
                  {
               Viewbag.LoginError = "Please Login to use this page";
              filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
      new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary {
          {"controller", "Account"}, {"action", "Logon"}
                  }
          {

          }
      base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
  }
  ```

  add to your login page a div that shows `@(Viewbag.LoginError)`. This would render blank if unpopulated.
- A third way is to create a custom Authorization filter which redirects and sets an error message in a V@(ViewData["LoginError"].

add to your login page a div that shows `@(ViewData["LoginError"]`. This would render blank if unpopulated.

**note** I'm least certain or comfortable with this last method.